# $r\mapsto ar$ is injective iff $a$ is not a zero divisor - implicit assumption in solution.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking at the following practice problem:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Show that
$$m_a:R\rightarrow R, m_a(r)=ar$$
is injective if and only if $a$ is not a zero divisor.

Now $a$ is zero divisor clearly means that $m_a$ is not injective. For the other direction, the solution manual states that

> If $m_a$ is not injective, we can find $0\ne r\in R$ with $m_a(r)=0$, so $a$ is a zero divisor.

I don't see why we can assume that $0$ has multiple pre-images and not some other arbitrary element. Is the solution wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Because $m$ is a homomorphism, so not being injective is equivalent to $m$ having a non trivial kernel. $m(r)=m(s) \implies m(r-s)=0$ and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $m_a$ is not injective, there are elements $r_1,r_2\in R$, with $r_1\ne r_2$, such that $ar_1=ar_2$. But then $a(r_1-r_2)=0$, and $r_1-r_2\ne0$.